# Should I use proper punctuation for single sentence alert/notification popups?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Is it necessary to use a period for single sentence notification boxes? Even though its considered proper grammar to do so, it just looks ugly and feels too formal.

Here are two screenies for comparison (first includes period, second doesn't).

[alt text http://wordofjohn.com/files/stack_alert_1.png](http://wordofjohn.com/files/stack_alert_1.png)

[alt text http://wordofjohn.com/files/stack_alert_2.png](http://wordofjohn.com/files/stack_alert_2.png)

Comment: If the program knows you are in edit mode, and that you want to switch modules, and that you need to exit edit mode before switching, why doesn't it automatically switch for you? Why tell the user to do something the computer already knows how to do?

Comment: There might numbers of reason for this. The first one that come to my mind is that the user would probably lose their changes if he quits the edit mode and you don't necessarily want to save the changes nor loose them.

Comment: Bryan, because there are certain operations that take time to complete, such as uploading a file. The file needs to be uploaded and processed, as this affects what will appear in the view mode (also, hiding the yui disconnects the event handlers, breaking any error handling)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good grammar shows to your customers that you took time to make a good software even where others might not took time.

This way they can expect the best out of you and your company.

Answer (score 8):

Can't go wrong with correct grammar

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a full sentence to tell the user what to do, then I think proper grammar is important, although I always stay away from exclamation points, I find them annoying.

Comment: Amen on the exclamation points. Dialogs should serve to inform, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

It is more preference that anything, but I like to maintain the best grammar possible in any situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'd vote No.

These alerts are like signposts or roadsigns, they need to present a brief but important message as succinctly as possible.

My reasoning extended - I think it's subjective, and so I doubt anyone's going to have a bad user experience because of the presense or absence of a full stop (period). A question mark might be confusing if it was left out, but a full stop is kind of implicit.

Comment: A period would make it less brief?

Comment: You wouldn't see a full stop on a no smoking sign for example was my point.

Comment: A period marks the end of a sentence, but because there is only, and always, one sentence I feel that I shouldn't need one. And by using one in this context would appear overly formal and stately.

Comment: I think these (and most) dialogs are a bit more verbose than a road-sign. They're short, but they're not "STOP" or "GIVE WAY".

Comment: I find when I'm reading something that otherwise looks like a full sentence, little hints like punctuation at the end allow me to parse it just that little bit quicker. When reading the line without the period, for about ¼ of a second my brain went "switching modules *what*?".

Comment: True, but it's only one sentence. Think of a warning sticker or sign like "no user servicable parts inside" or something. It's subjective, but if it's only once sentence, you probably won't get a full stop.

Answer (score 2):

In both instances you capitalized the first word in the sentence so I would say go with proper grammar

but it really is a preference

Answer (score 2):

If you use periods at the end of your sentences, then users will know that the string hasn't been truncated (well OK, they won't *know* that it hasn't been truncated, but it's a good indicator. Plus, as others have said, it shows you went to the trouble to get it right.

I can't remember - what do MS/Apple do?

Comment: +1 for tuncation indication. Missing punctuation always makes me feel like something went wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain my preference with an analogy.

I used to work at a bookstore where they sold Bibles. Some of them were Cambridge calfskin leather bound deluxe editions that came in special boxes for over US$100.00 each. Some of them were mass market paperback throw-away versions for US$1.99 each. The cheap ones often had glaring grammatical and spelling errors. I don't think this was a coincidence.

Regardless of where my software is going to be used or what it is for, I try to do my best to make sure it gets put (metaphorically) on the high-quality, expensive rack. Every time. Even at the risk of sounding "too formal".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the string as a normal resource, you (or someone else in your project) could use the text in another context, which would mean you need to keep track of which resources contain a period or not.